# find number of child divs which can fit into parent divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have the following scenario:
I have an API which returns multiple div's. And in my UI, I have one parent div in which i need to show these div's. The condition is, if child div is overflowing parent, I need to show them on next page.

For eg: lets say my API is returning string like this:

```
<div class="ab0"></div>
<div class="ab1"></div>
<div class="ab2"></div>
<div class="ab3"></div>
<div class="ab4"></div>
```

and the parent div can fit in only ab0, ab1, ab2. Then I want to show these 3 div's 1st and when user click on '>' symbol I need to show ab3, ab4. Also if ab2 is partially overflowing and if I can show only overflowing part on next page, that will be great.

Is there any way I can do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading) helps.

Comment: There is a way by Javascript. Get the height of the parent container and of the children and calculate how many children can be into the container.

Comment: @RobMoll I think in lazy loading i cant control the visibility of already loaded items. and also if ab0 ab1 are loaded i dont want to unload them if user is just loading ab2. Is there a way i can solve this?

Comment: @Azu , I thought of same, but how can i get height of child divs?  Could you please give example of same? thanks

Comment: @Azu and also, is it possible to divide the content of ab2 if it is partially overflowing?

Comment: Is the height of the divs set by CSS or it depends on the content?

Comment: It depends on the contents

Comment: If it depends on the content, and you don't know the content until after you load the divs, then no, there is no way to predict how many divs you should load.

Answer (score 0):

A simple suggestion is to use the system's scroll functionality.

The system 'knows' how much it can show at once and as long as you can find out the height of the parent div you can move up and down the children (or part children if an exact number don't fit into the parent at once) using Javascript scrollTop.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
const h = parent.offsetHeight;
let page = 0;
const lastPage = Math.floor((parent.scrollHeight + 1) / h);

function next() {
  if (page < lastPage) {
    page++;
    parent.scrollTop = parent.scrollTop + h;
  }
}

function prev() {
  if (page > 0) {
    page--;
    parent.scrollTop = parent.scrollTop - h;
  }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 64px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.parent div {
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="ab0">0</div>
  <div class="ab1">1</div>
  <div class="ab2">2</div>
  <div class="ab3">3</div>
  <div class="ab4">4</div>
</div>
<button onclick="prev();"><</button>
<button onclick="next();">></button>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this, user will see a above contents scrolled r8? I wanted to show it as page view. But if that is not possible, I can use this.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand 'a above contents scrolled r8'. Also 'page view'. It's up to you how big you make the container, where you place it etc.

Comment: I mean user will see content of ab0, ab1, ab2 as if they are going up?

Comment: Ah, so they see the actual scroll - is that the problem. I'm sure we can do something about that.

Comment: yes. So I dont want that behavior. If we can control that, then it will be great. We need to hide them directly instead of showing them moving up

Comment: We can hide while repositioning the contents (the scroll) but I think there is a practical flaw in the method as a whole, you may get part (in the vertical direction) text lines possibly (and if there are images, split images).